# Is there a name for (pre)sheaves satisfying this transitivity condition?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Suppose that $F:\mathscr{C}^{op} \to Set$ is a presheaf. For an object $C$, denote by $Aut(C)$ the group of isomorphisms $f:C \to C.$ There is a canonical action $Aut(C)$ of on $F(C).$ Is there a special name for those $F$ for which all of these actions are transitive? Has this situation been studied? Does this imply any nice categorical consequences? If $F$ is also a sheaf for a Grothendiek topology on $\mathscr{C},$ does $F$ satisfy any nice conditions in the associated topos of sheaves?

Answer (score 2):

At least for fiber functors from Galois categories to finite sets this is the well-known notion of Galois objects. See [Lenstra's notes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf), section 3.14. For example, if $L/K$ is a finite separable field extension, then it is Galois iff $\mathrm{Aut}_K(L)$ acts transitively on $\hom(L,\overline{K})$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not well-versed in these matters, but I believe Olivia Caramello uses something like this in her toposical formulation of Galois theory. See [her paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0300) and, if you can understand French, this brief [lecture series](https://sites.google.com/site/logiquecategorique/Contenus/theorie-de-galois-topologique) expounding it.